# Arduino Eclipse Can not resolve Serial

Tags: eclipse, arduino

I have been trying to set up Eclipse and the Arduino libraries. 
I have followed the instructions located at this URL.
http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse

The issue I am having is that my project can not resolve Serial.
Anyone have an idea of why this might be?
I am using Arduino 1.0 and the instruction were written for a pre 1.0 version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Setting the preference windows->preferences->C/C++->indexer->index unused headers.

Setting the preference windows->preferences->C/C++->indexer->index source and header files opened in the editor.

Setting the preference windows->preferences->C/C++->indexer->Files to index upfront . Add arduino.h and or WProgram.h.

Do next four in this sequence
 Right click the project->index->Search for unresolved includes.
Right click the project->index->Freshen all Files.
Right click the project->index->Update with modified files.
Right click the project->index->Rebuild.
```

Comment: "Files to index upfront"   not available, and not needed anymore for recent versions of Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Doing what the Plugin FAQ [here](http://www.baeyens.it/eclipse/Arduino%20eclipse%20plugin%20FAQ.html#bugs) says is correct, but not sufficient, at least not if you work in Windows.

You will need to add a path to **Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Path and symbols**

- Under the tab "includes" click on add
- Select the flag "add to all
  configurations"
- Type this path: `path to Arduino
  IDE installation directory\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include`

In my case the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include`

After this eclipse will ask you if you want to rebuild the index and then all standard symbols will be correctly resolved

Answer (score 1):

do  "Arduino Eclipse Extensions" upgrade in Help->Check for updates